# How to launch swing app with jetbrains layouts in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I've created app in IDEA with some swing layouts. I want to launch it in Netbeans in order to profile. But I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: contentPane cannot be set to null.
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.setContentPane(JRootPane.java:603)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.setContentPane(JDialog.java:991)
    at TransTest.<init>(TransTest.java:44)
    at TransTest.main(TransTest.java:284)
```

What files etc I should supply in order to run it?

Comment: Show us line 284 of TransTest.java

Comment: TransTest dialog = new TransTest();

Comment: javax.swing.JDialog.setContentPane(JDialog.java:991) at TransTest.(TransTest.java:44) at --- Is saying you are setting contentPane to null, which wont work, on line 44.

Comment: But it works in IDEA. Brobably some extra initialization is made by ide...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As can be read on the [UI designer webpage](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html)

> Unique Byte-code instrumentation techniques allow you to get rid of complicated Swing code in your Java sources. IntelliJ IDEA's GUI-compiler transparently generates all necessary code needed to create and lay out form components. The GUI-compiler has been integrated into IntelliJ IDEA's make functionality, and is also available as a separate Ant task delivered together with the IntelliJ IDEA distribution. There is also an option to generate Java source code instead of using the byte-code instrumentation approach.

So [generate Java source code](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/gui-designer.html) and use that in NetBeans, or simply hand-code your layouts rather then using a UI designer.

Comment: @stiv I added a link to the relevant help page